# Is there a better way to specify optional elements in rules of a CFG?

Tags: grammar, bison, context-free-grammar

Consider a language and a compiler to design and develop for it.
In this language there is a particular statement that is part of the grammar: `(=<identifier>)`. This piece can be recognized by the compiler. But spaces are allowed between the brackets and the equal sign and the identifier. So I have these possibilities:

```
(=<identifier>)
( = <identifier> )
(=identifier )
( =identifier )
...
```

Without considering the whole grammar but just the rules to handle this language feature, I have something like this (in a Bison-like syntax for grammar rules):

```
statement: OBRCKT EQ ID CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT S EQ S ID S CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT S EQ ID S CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT S EQ S ID CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT S EQ ID CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT EQ S ID S CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT EQ ID S CBRCKT
         | OBRCKT EQ S ID CBRCKT
         | ...
```

The space terminal `S` can appear or not. But the way rules are, I need to specify all possible combinations... Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Comment: I think that sort of thing is usually handled at the lexical analysis/tokenizing level, rather than explicitly in the grammar.

Comment: So it is better to reduce during the lexical analysis to one only possible form? Well makes sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jim commented, use your lexical tool to handle these cases instead of writing them into the productions of your grammar.

For example, I commonly use Flex for lexical analysis and Bison to define my grammar (probably as you have done).

You can achieve the result that you want with something like the following (this is just an example so it's pretty simple and cannot do much):

lexicalAnalyzer.l

```
 /* lexicalAnalyzer.l
    Specifications of tokens for some language.
 */
%{

%}

/*
 *  Definitions of regular expressions
 *  Note: You capture whitespace here...
*/

WSPACE      [ \t\r]+ //We take care of the spaces here...

/*
 *  Tokens
*/
%%

"=" {
        printf("TOKEN: EQ   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);             
        return T_EQ;
    }
"(" {
        printf("TOKEN: OBRCKT   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);
        return T_OBRCKT;
    }
")" {
        printf("TOKEN: CBRCKT   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);
        return T_CBRCKT;
    }
"<" {
        printf("TOKEN: LT   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);
        return T_LT;
    }
">" {
        printf("TOKEN: GT   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);
        return T_GT;
    }
"identifier"    {
                printf("TOKEN: IDENT   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);
            return T_IDENT;
             }  
{WSPACE}    { }
.       {
                 printf("TOKEN: UNKNOWN   LEXEME: %s\n", yytext);
                 return T_UNKNOWN;
            }
%%
```

syntaxAnalyzer.y

```
/*
      syntaxAnalyzer.y

      To create syntax analyzer:
        flex file.l
        bison file.y
        g++ file.tab.c -o file_parser
        file_parser < inputFileName
 */

/*
 *  Declaration section.
 */

%{

    #include <stdio.h>
    void printRule(const char *lhs, const char *rhs);
    int yyerror(const char *s) {
        printf("Error!");
    }
    extern "C" {
        int yyparse(void);
        int yylex(void);
        int yywrap() {return 1;}
    }
%}

/*
 *  Token declarations
*/
%token  T_OBRCKT T_CBRCKT
%token  T_LT T_GT T_EQ   
%token  T_IDENT T_UNKNOWN

/*
 *  Starting point.
 */
%start  N_START

/*
 *  Translation rules.
 */
%%
N_START     : N_STATEMENT
            {
                printRule("START", "STATEMENT");
                printf("\n---- Completed parsing ----\n\n");
                return 0;
            }
            ;

N_STATEMENT : T_OBRCKT T_EQ T_LT T_IDENT T_GT T_CBRCKT
            {
            printRule("EXPR", "T_OBRCKT T_EQ T_LT T_IDENT T_GT T_CBRCKT");

            }
            ;
%%

#include "lex.yy.c"
extern FILE *yyin;

void printRule(const char *lhs, const char *rhs) {
  printf("%s -> %s\n", lhs, rhs);
  return;
}

int main() {
  do {
    yyparse();
  } while (!feof(yyin));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Understood. Basically we get rid of spaces when running the lexer so that grammar rules will get much more compact...

Comment: @Andry Exactly, and then you only need one production instead of many complicated ones in this case.

Comment: However, don't waste your time writing log messages by hand to see when a rule is matched, rather, have a look at `%option debug` in Flex's manual.

Comment: Thankyou so much to everyone... as you were probably thinking I am a newbie to this so every suggestion is more than welcome.